# Using a method from one class into another class

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

I am having trouble with my last method. I am informed that I have to use my adjust method from my BankAccount.class in my monthlyFee method in my bank class and I can not figure it out. I've tried multiple different things and can not get it to work. We need to adjust the balances of the accounts with the monthly fee.

> Bank.java:33: error: method adjust in class BankAccount cannot be
>   applied to given types; BankAccount.adjust();                     ^
>   required: double   found: no arguments   reason: actual and formal
>   argument lists differ in length 1 error
>
> Bank.java:33: error: double cannot be dereferenced fee.adjust(); 1
>   error
>
> Bank.java:33: error: cannot find symbol  bank.BankAccount.adjust();
>   symbol: variable BankAccount location: variable bank of type
>   BankAccount[] 1 error

**BankAccount.class**

```
public class BankAccount {

String owner; // owner of account
int accountNumber; // integer account number
double balance = 0.0; // account balance
double amount; // adjusted amount to balance
String balanceFmt = "%.2f"; // string format for 2 decimal places

public BankAccount(String owner, int accountNumber) { //Constructor for the bank account
   this.owner = owner;
   this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
}

public double adjust(double amount) { //method to adjust balance
   this.balance += amount;
   return balance;
}
public String toString() { // method to print out account info
   return owner + " owns the account " + accountNumber + " with the balance of $" + String.format(balanceFmt,balance);

}
public double getBalance() { // method to get balance of accounts
   return balance;   
}
}
```

**Bank.class**

```
public class Bank {

BankAccount bank[];

public Bank() { // constructor for making a 10 account array
   bank = new BankAccount[10];
}

public void addAccount(BankAccount accounts) { // add account for giving numbers to accounts
   for(int i = 0; i < bank.length; i++) {
      if(bank[i] == null) {
         bank[i] = accounts;
         break;
      }
   }
}

BankAccount getAccount(int i) { //obtain account from BankAccount class
   return bank[i];
}

public void printAccounts() { //prints out account statuses
   for(int i = 0; i < bank.length; i++) {
      if(bank[i] != null) {
      System.out.println(bank[i]);
      }
   }
}

public void monthlyFee(double fee) { //monthly fee for bank accounts
   for(int i = 0; i < bank.length; i++) {
      if(bank[i] != null) {
      } //I have tried BankAccount.adjust() and couldn't work, bank[i].adjust() nothing seems to work
   }
}
}
```

**BankTest.class**

```
public class BankTest { 
/*
 * test - set up a bank and add accounts
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {
// Code to test Bank and BankAccount classes
int errors = 0;
double fee = -2.95;

Assignment assignment = new Assignment();
assignment.homework("Homework 2a");

System.out.println("\nCreate bank1");
Bank bank1 = new Bank();
System.out.println("\nOne account");
BankAccount bankAccount1 = new BankAccount("Joe Mac", 1234);
bankAccount1.adjust(1000.0);
bank1.addAccount(bankAccount1);
bank1.printAccounts();
System.out.println("\nTwo accounts");
BankAccount bankAccount2 = new BankAccount("Sally Ride", 2345);
bankAccount2.adjust(2000.0);
bank1.addAccount(bankAccount2);
bank1.printAccounts();
System.out.println("\nThree accounts");
BankAccount bankAccount3 = new BankAccount("Pat Armstrong", 3456);
bankAccount3.adjust(3000.0);
bank1.addAccount(bankAccount3);
bank1.printAccounts();
System.out.println("\nMonthly Fee");
bank1.monthlyFee(fee);
bank1.printAccounts();
System.out.println("\nErrors:");

if (bank1.getAccount(0).getBalance() != 997.05) {
    errors += 1;
    System.out.println("Balance for account at index 0 does not match $997.05");
}
if (bank1.getAccount(1).getBalance() != 1997.05)
{
    errors += 1;
    System.out.println("Balance for account at index 1 does not match $1997.05");
}
if (bank1.getAccount(2).getBalance() != 2997.05)
{
    errors += 1;
    System.out.println("Balance for account at index 2 does not match $2997.05");
}
if (errors == 0)
    System.out.println("No errors found!!!");
}
}
```

Any help and guidance is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You need to pass a double value while calling the given bank account object's adjust method

Comment: And always post the exact code that gives you the error. Not put up the error content, but to then have *different* code with a comment in the place that caused the problem! Always have a [mcve]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you forgot to pass the fee parameter to adjust() method.  Following code works perfectly fine

```
 public void monthlyFee(double fee) { //monthly fee for bank accounts
    for(int i = 0; i < bank.length; i++) {
      if(bank[i] != null) {
        System.out.println(bank[i].adjust(fee));
      } //I have tried BankAccount.adjust() and couldn't work, bank[i].adjust() nothing seems to work
    }
  }
```

Create bank1

One account
Joe Mac owns the account 1234 with the balance of $1000.00

Two accounts
Joe Mac owns the account 1234 with the balance of $1000.00
Sally Ride owns the account 2345 with the balance of $2000.00

Three accounts
Joe Mac owns the account 1234 with the balance of $1000.00
Sally Ride owns the account 2345 with the balance of $2000.00
Pat Armstrong owns the account 3456 with the balance of $3000.00

Monthly Fee
997.05
1997.05
2997.05
Joe Mac owns the account 1234 with the balance of $997.05
Sally Ride owns the account 2345 with the balance of $1997.05
Pat Armstrong owns the account 3456 with the balance of $2997.05

Errors:

### No errors found!!!

Comment: I tried this similar but I never put the fee in the parenthesis. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: when you check your test code, you find that it passes a double value when that *adjust()* method is invoked!

Your other code (the one that leads to the error) seems to not pass any double when invoking that method!

Comment: @A.O'Mary You are very welcome. And I appreciate the quick accept, even when it went to another answer ;-)